# Lógica de ponteiros

Tags: c++, ponteiro, característica-linguagem

Em C++, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
int variavel[10][10];
int** variavel;
```

Mas e quando eu quiser criar um array 2d, em que eu posso ter a primeira parte "ilimitada" e a segunda com limite?

```
tipo ponteiro nova_variavel[limite]
```

E o "inverso"?

```
tipo nova_variavel[limite] ponteiro
```

Por exemplo:

```
int* a[5]; //Ponteiro de arrays
```

Ou

```
std::vector<int*> a; //Array de ponteiros

char* A[6];
A[1] = "Hello,";
A[2] = " World";
std::array<char*,2> a;
a[1] = "Hello,";
a[2] = "World!"; // <- Repare 1 caractere a mais. É pouco, mas pode fazer diferença.
```

Comment: A pergunta já está respondida, mas se me permitirem eu gostaria de adicionar que, apesar de ser mais fácil de usar, arrays multi-dimensionais são bem menos eficientes que os unidimensionais, seja pelo número de alocações, seja porque a memória fica em lugares diferentes e prejudica o cache. Você sempre vai poder usar um array[100] no lugar de um array[10][10].

Comment: @C.E.Gesser na verdade, o melhor é usar um contâiner do STL :). Mas SE eu precisasse, usaria arrays bidimensionais para deixar mais organizado (dependendo do caso, claro!).

Comment: @C.E.Gesser a alocação de uma multidimensional é também linear na memória. E dizer `array[a][b]` é tão eficiente quanto seria `array[a*10+b]`. Não há tanta diferença assim.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Um contâiner causará alocação dinâmica e potencialmente não linear (exceto `std::array`). Então eles não são o ideal em todos os casos. Mas sim, são a alternativa mais fácil e com menor chance de erros.

Comment: Para um array é verdade, estava me refirindo mais aos casos onde se faz algo como `int **array = new int*[N]; for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) array[i] = new int[M];`, eu deveria ter sido mais explícito. Quanto aos contêineres, `std::vector` sempre tem uma alocação contígua. Quase nunca se erra escolhendo ele.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser STL Forever!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays e ponteiros são conceitos bastante diferentes. Um ponteiro nada tem haver com uma "array ilimitada". Vamos lá:

```
int lista[10][10];
```

Aqui você está declarando uma array bidimensional com 100 elementos. O **nome** dessa array é `lista`. Quando você escreve `lista[4][2]` você acessa um elemento e isso resulta em um `int`. No entanto se você escrever apenas `lista` na sua expressão, ou seja, quando você tentar acessar a array pelo nome, ela **decairá** em um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento. O detalhe aqui é que não é possível representar o tipo array diretamente, ele decairá em um ponteiro sempre que requisitado. Pode-se fazer o seguinte então:

```
int lista[10][10];
int* ponteiro1 = lista; // ponteiro1 é &lista[0][0]
int* ponteiro2 = lista[3]; // ponteiro2 é &lista[3][0]
```

Já quando você faz o seguinte

```
int** ponteiro;
```

Está apenas criando um ponteiro que aponta para um ponteiro que aponta para um `int`. Não há arrays aqui. A notação `ponteiro[2][3]` que é possível representa um pouco de álgebra com ponteiros, sendo equivalente a `*(*(ponteiro+2)+3)`. Isso pode nem mesmo resultar em um local válido da memoria.

Ainda outra possibilidade:

```
int* lista2[10]; // array de ponteiros
```

Aqui você tem uma simples lista unidimensional, cujo elemento é um ponteiro `int*`.

A última notação da sua pergunta (`tipo nova_variavel[limite] ponteiro`) teria objetivo de criar um ponteiro de nome `nova_variavel` que aponte para uma array de `limite` elementos do tipo `tipo`? Nesse caso sua definição é escrita assim:

```
int (*variavel)[10]; // ponteiro de arrays
```

Não tão intuitivo, talvez. Um exemplo:

```
int main() {
    int array[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int (*ponteiro_para_array)[10] = &array;
    cout << (*ponteiro_para_array)[5] << endl; // mostra 6
}
```

Uma forma de escapar dessas complicações na hora de declarar uma variável com um tipo não usual, é nomear cada parte do seu tipo. Por exemplo (C++11):

```
using int10 = int[10]; // Cria um alias para a array de 10 ints
int10* variavel; // Exatamente o mesmo que a declaração anterior
```

Comment: Heheh, @GuilhermeBernal trabalho com a linguagem há 5 anos, eu sei as diferenças de array e tudo, mas, qual a diferença de `char array[] = "TEST";` e `char* array = "TEST";` esteticamente? Eu sei, dereferencing...

Comment: @LucasHenrique `char array[] = "TEST";` cria a sua própria copia da string enquanto que o `char* array = "TEST";` aponta para uma cópia "compartilhada" e somente leitura. São bem diferentes, semanticamente.

Comment: por isso que ninguem usaria o operador de de-referencia nesses casos.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Por que não? Posso usar `*array` para ler `'T'` em ambos os casos.

Comment: Opa. Me confundi - referência: Só se você for pegar o endereço na memória

Comment: @LucasHenrique no caso da array, o máximo que você pode fazer é pegar uma referencia para o primeiro elemento, não da array em si. Mas no caso do ponteiro, pode ser útil em alguma função que queira modificar o argumento, movendo o ponteiro ou algo do tipo. Falho agora em encontrar um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que ter um "array de ponteiros" faça sentido, mas um "ponteiro de arrays" não. Se você declara:

```
int *variavel[10];
```

O que você está dizendo é: "aloque memória na pilha para 10 ponteiros para inteiro, e me dê o endereço do primeiro deles". Nesse caso, a segunda parte é "ilimitada" de certa forma - já que você pode fazer cada um desses ponteiros referenciar um array de qualquer tamanho (desde que você **aloque memória** para cada um deles também, é claro).

Já o inverso (que não vou dar exemplo, pois que eu saiba não existe) seria como dizer: "crie um ponteiro que só referencie arrays de inteiros **de tamanho 10**". Ou seja, você está impondo uma **restrição adicional** (*constraint*) nos objetos que aquele ponteiro pode referenciar, e isso não é algo suportado pela linguagem C++ (ou por qualquer linguagem que eu conheça). Pois a única restrição que você pode colocar a um ponteiro é a especificação do seu tipo - e nada referente ao seu **conteúdo**.